# htmlspecialchars breaks json_decode

Tags: php, json, htmlspecialchars

To prevent XSS attack, i have used below code.

```
/* To prevent XSS Attack */
    public function __construct($id,$module=null) {
        $_GET = $this->clean($_GET);
        $_POST = $this->clean($_POST);
        $_REQUEST = $this->clean($_REQUEST);

        //Call parent constuct
        parent::__construct($id,$module=null);
    }

    /* To prevent XSS Attack */
    protected function clean($data) {
        if (is_array($data)) {
             foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
                unset($data[$key]);
                $data[$this->clean($key)] = $this->clean($value);
            }
        } else {
            $data = htmlspecialchars($data, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
        }
        return $data;
   }
```

It will clean every get, post requests. It's working fine.

But now it creates the problem, in code there is lots of place where i am using json_decode.
example: in one place i have a json_encoded post variable, to decode it i have to use below code:

```
 $objclass->fields = json_decode(html_entity_decode($_POST['fields'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'),true);
```

If i simply use  `json_decode($_POST['fields'],true);` then it will fail because `$_POST['fields']` data is encrypted using htmlspecialchars.

So is there a way to so `json_decode` will work directly without having to implement `html_entity_decode`?

Comment: You sending JSON data wrapped in HTML tags for some reason? If not then don't escape it when sending it out. Also, There is no need to 'clean' data on the way in.

Comment: yes, i have made the extension in yii which return html.

Comment: You shouldn't automatically run "htmlspecialchars" on all incoming requests. It's only going to "clean" the data in a specific case (when printing HTML) but it's going to mess it up for other cases. You should escape data at the moment it is relevant (before printing it as HTML, before an SQL query, etc.).

Comment: i have cleaned it because sometime those data goes back as it is and render those data in js.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way. If you apply `htmlspecialchars()` to all request data, you'll have to use `html_entity_decode()` to get it back in the raw form.

This technique is bad in the same way [magic quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) were bad. I recommend against using it. Instead, use a templating engine and escape the individual variables when needed.

Comment: Actually project is huge, we cant go in and add that for each variable. that's why we have added that for all request data.

Comment: Use a templating engine and this problem disappears. No need for manual escaping or storing HTML in the database because you render it without escaping.. If you can't for some reason them I'm afraid you're stuck with your clunky code.

Comment: Not possible. But you could make your own that calls `html_entity_decode()` and then `json_decode()`.

Comment: last one, what if i use it in __destruct?

Comment: It shouldn't matter where you call the function.